# Set up minimal user rights

Tags: windows-xp, security, privileges

I'm going to run highly dangerous executables in Windows XP residing inside virtual machine. Due to a large amount of dangerous executables, I can't restore VM to snapshot after every run of an executable. So I would like to run them via (job object and) CreateProcessWithLogon WinAPI (run from another user) to minimize a damage to VM.

How do I set up a user, such that executables running under his rights would have standard input/output (console) rights only or something near to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a guest account. That's the most restricted user that is built in

Comment: Sometimes guest user can modify desktop, sometimes not. I've seen a couple of other differences in guest user privileges (though, these were high-level ones too). Could you provide some links on how to set such things up?

Comment: You'd have to check out Group Policies. Google has millions of hits about it